# How to add a Value to Each Card in a Deck of Cards

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have been stuck on this for a few days I have the deck of cards created and it works but I don't know how I would make each card have a value without using 52 if/elif statements for a BlackJack game. How would i make 10 of spades = 10, 9 of clubs = 9 etc.

```
    import random 

#card class to take suit and value self
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val
        
    def show(self):
        print (f"{self.value} of {self.suit}")
        
        
#creates the deck class  
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build() 
        
        #appends each suit and each val of the card to give us 52 cards (4 * 13 = 52)
    def build(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]: 
            for v in range (1,14):
                if v == 1:
                    self.cards.append(Card(s,"Ace")) #code that turns 1s into aces
                elif v == 11:
                    self.cards.append(Card(s,"Queen")) #code that turns 11 into queens
                elif v == 12:
                    self.cards.append(Card(s, "King")) #code that turns 12 into kings
                elif v == 13:
                    self.cards.append(Card(s,"Jack")) #code that turns 13 into Jacks
                else:
                    self.cards.append(Card(s,v))
        
    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()
    
    #shuffle method using the Fisher Yates Shuffle Algorithm
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]
    
    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()


#dealer class
class Dealer:
    global currentCard
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []
    
    def draw(self,deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self
    
    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            currentCard = card.show()


    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    dealer = Dealer("Dealer")
    dealer.draw(deck)
    dealer.showHand()
```

Comment: use a dictionary `{1:"Ace", 12:"King"}` etc...  then iterate over the cards and assign the name that the dictionary gives you

Comment: hey thanks for the response, any idea how i can integrate it (probably just changing the append to the list into a dict right?) but then how would i access those values so when the dealer "draws" a card it adds it to the users total

Comment: ok cool im going to try to incorporate this

Comment: `self.cards.append(Card(s,mydict[v]))`

Comment: You want each `Card` to have a value. The natural thing to do is to set `self.value` in the `Card` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In term of the value you should first figure out where you want to handle that functionality. In terms of generally naming the cards you could assume them to be ordered in a pattern so that they are defined by their number and use modulo to get the suit and value. For example:

```
for i in range(0,52)
    Card(suit=i//13,val=i%13)
```

The modulo operator % just gives you "the rest" of a division, so if you operate with whole numbers (no decimal fractions) then 10//3 is 3 and a rest of 1 because 3*3+1 = 10. So if you use modulo 13 (cards in a suit), that should give you a number between 0 and 12 (or 1 and 13 if you add 1) while i//13 rounds down to the nearest whole number which would give you a number between 0 and 3 (or 1 and 4) which can be used for the suits.

And once you have that you can use a dictionary or just a list with suits and card names that translate the numbers to names. Now in terms of values you could either derive them from the card names in a similar fashion but I'd rather deal with them on the level of the game logic as for example and ace could be both a 1 and an 11 (right?) so dealing with that when it's necessary would make more sense than to assign a value at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Every card needs two attributes - a suit and a value. The value will depend on the type of card game you're "playing". A common approach would be to assign values in the range 2->14

Consider this and note the absence of cumbersome if/else constructs:

```
import random

class CARD:
    suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    names = {2: 'Two',
             3: 'Three',
             4: 'Four',
             5: 'Five',
             6: 'Six',
             7: 'Seven',
             8: 'Eight',
             9: 'Nine',
             10: 'Ten',
             11: 'Jack',
             12: 'Queen',
             13: 'King',
             14: 'Ace'}

    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{CARD.names[self.value]} of {self.suit} has a value of {self.value}'


class DECK:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = None
    def get_cards(self):
        if self.cards is None:
            self.cards = [CARD(CARD.suits[n % 4], n % 13 + 2) for n in range(52)]
        return self.cards
    def get_random_card(self):
        return random.choice(self.get_cards())


D = DECK()

# pick some cards at random
for _ in range(5):
    print(D.get_random_card())
```

**Output (similar to):**

```
Queen of Spades has a value of 12
Five of Diamonds has a value of 5
Nine of Diamonds has a value of 9
Four of Clubs has a value of 4
Three of Clubs has a value of 3
```

Comment: But Queen of Spades has a value of 10. Though that is a matter of the output not how they are internally handled.

Comment: As I said in my preamble, the values you assign depend on what you're "playing". In some card games, J, Q & K are considered equivalent (typically with a numeric value of 10) and then Ace would have some other value - typically either 1 or 11 or even both!